# I cannot install spatemplates in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, single-page-application

When I try to execute the following command:

```
dotnet --install microsoft.aspnetcore.spatemplates::*
```

I got the following error

> "the folder is not empty"

, and the template are not installed.

[image: click to see the error image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the command is like this

```
dotnet new -i "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*"
```

Which will install SPA templates.

[image: dotnet cli - SPA templates]

Ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-install-script

Comment: thanks for the answer, but It didn't work, the message still is there.